# npm starts to execute many prestart scripts

Tags: node.js, npm

Ok, I have a project where I use npm. I need it to compile several .coffee scripts.

I need to execute multiple prestart scripts, like:

```
  "scripts": {
     "prestart": "coffee -c ./file1.coffee",
     "prestart": "coffee -c ./file2.coffee",
     "prestart": "coffee -c ./file3.coffee",
     "prestart": "coffee -c ./file4.coffee",
    "start": "node ./file1.js"
  },
```

But it only seems to execute the last one, and it doesn't let me append many scripts on one like:

```
"prestart": "coffee -c ./file1.coffee; coffee -c./file2.coffee"
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

wrap them in a parent script

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "sh ./make-coffee.sh",
  "start": "node ./file1.js"
},

//make-coffee.sh
#!/bin/bash
coffee -c ./file1.coffee
coffee -c ./file2.coffee
coffee -c ./file3.coffee
coffee -c ./file4.coffee
```

or another (unix-only) solution is to run multiple commands. I don't know what happens if the early commands fail.

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "coffee -c ./file1.coffee; coffee -c ./file2.coffee; coffee -c ./file3.coffee; coffee -c ./file4.coffee",
  "start": "node ./file1.js"
},
```

Comment: separing them with ; didn't work, it looked for the file "file1.coffee;"

Comment: BTW If anyone else knows a good cross-platform solution to this I am interested!

Comment: try this:

  "prestart": "coffee -c ./file1.coffee ./file2.coffee ./file3.coffee ./file4.coffee",

Comment: thx @Swiollvfer I am actually looking for any generic solution to run an arbitrary number of commands in a single cross platform npm script... this specific scenario works because you can pass multiple files to the coffee binary

Comment: @Plato Contrary to `;` as command separator `&&` is supported in most shells (including Windows), it also fails fast and doesn't try to continue running your script a command in the middle blew up.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `&&` like this

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "coffee -c ./file1.coffee && coffee -c ./file2.coffee && coffee -c ./file3.coffee && coffee -c ./file4.coffee",
  "start": "node ./file1.js"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

**if it's not a lot of scripts,**
you can handle it with the same `start` script

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "coffee -c ./file1.coffee && coffee -c ./file2.coffee && node ./file1.js"
},
```