# How to chain custom script in package.json to call prestart mongod?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, package.json, npm-scripts

Trying to streamline my *package.json* and local development with a custom script to run Nodemon. I'm currently building an app with a front and back end I need to call `mongod` before `start` and before my custom in two tabs however I'm running into an issue.

`mongod` will only run in the terminal if the terminal path is set to local from testing and I've read:

- [Correct way of starting mongodb and express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316696/correct-way-of-starting-mongodb-and-express)
- [npm starts to execute many prestart scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609470/npm-starts-to-execute-many-prestart-scripts)
- [How to npm start at a different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172442/how-to-npm-start-at-a-different-directory)
- [How do I add a custom script to my package.json file that runs a javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433461/how-do-i-add-a-custom-script-to-my-package-json-file-that-runs-a-javascript-file)

I can use `prestart` as:

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "cd && mongod",
    "start": "node app",
    "nodemon": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon app"
}
```

but I'm not seeing how I should chain a `prestart` with a custom scripts. When I try to chain it with `nodemon` as:

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "cd && mongod",
    "start": "node app",
    "nodemon": "cd && mongod && ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon app"
},
```

Nodemon is fired first than `mongodb` crashes in my package.json when I call Nodemon as:

```
npm run nodemon
```

How can I start `mongod` before starting `nodemon` in my development process through one command in the *package.json*?

Comment: This package might help you [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)